# Difference between Quad Half-Bridge and Dual H-Bridge driver ICs from the control point of view

Tags: stepper-motor, h-bridge

There are driver ICs consisting of either quad half-bridge (such as DRV8932) or dual H-bridge (such as DRV8428E). From the control point of view, what is the advantage of choosing quad half-bridge over dual H-bridge IC?

As far as I can see, dual H-bridge IC still has four control inputs, which I assume, can be controlled independently.

I am especially interested in case of bipolar stepper motor control.

Comment: Might not be a difference. Check against your requirements - what option covers all your needs at less cost.

Comment: That is what I am suspecting too, that there's no difference. But I would like to get a definitive answer.

Comment: <<<Inrush current limiting in brushed-DC applications>>> for the DRV8428 and 1500 mOhm in place of 900 mOhm

Comment: A definitive answer is- you probably don't know how to control a motor yet. Be sure you know what you are doing- maybe by asking other questions or by googling stuff. Then you will see that this specific question is easy to answer - when you know what you need.